# Deflate algorithm - deflate stream format - documentation beyond RFC1951

Tags: compression, http-compression

I'm interested on documentation of the deflate stream format or deflate algorithm which goes beyond RFC1951. Sample streams, implementation hints whatever may be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked on a streaming implementation of *deflate* once and found this description helpful:

http://www.zlib.net/feldspar.html

At first I tried the zlib source, but it is not an easy read.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) rather than rolling your own?

To support pre-compressed preambles, you could:

Use the raw API (those using `z_streamp` as a parameter) rather than the higher level wrappers.

Initialise the compressed preamble with it's own `z_streamp` and place the output in a buffer.

Then for all subsequent uses of the preamble, copy the preamble output buffer to the output, and copy the preamble's `z_streamp` and use that copy for compressing the subsequent bytes.

Comment: No, i couldn't because i need some functions that zlib don't provide.

Comment: What functions?  If you're specific, we might be able to help.

Comment: I need the possibility to insert pre compressed data in a deflate stream. I think it is hard to do. I've described the problem already in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410533/deflate-compression-stream-where-pre-compressed-data-can-be-inserted-does-a-net