# Can you pre-compress data files to be inserted into a zip file at a later time to improve performance?

Tags: c#, compression, zip

As part of our installer build, we have to zip thousands of large data files into about ten or twenty 'packages' with a few hundred (or even thousands of) files in each which are all dependent on being kept with the other files in the package. (They are versioned together if you will.)

Then during the actual install, the user selects which packages they want included on their system. This also lets them download updates to the packages from our site as one large, versioned file rather than asking them to download thousands of individual ones which could also lead to them being out of sync with others in the same package.

Since these are data files, some of them change regularly during the design and coding stages, meaning we then have to re-compress *all* files in that particular zip package, even if only one file has changed. This makes the packaging step of our installer build take well over an hour each time, with most of that going to re-compressing things that we haven't touched.

We've looked into leaving the zip packages alone, then replacing specific files inside them, but inserting and removing large files from the middle of a zip doesn't give us that much of a performance boost.  (A little, but not enough that its worth it.)

I'm wondering if its possible to pre-process files down into a cached raw 'compressed state' that matches how it would be written to the zip package, but only the data itself, not the zip header info, etc.

My thinking is if that is possible, during our build step, we would first look for any data file that doesn't have a compressed cache associated with it, and if not, we would compress that file and write the result to the cache.

Next we would simply append all of the caches together in a file stream, adding any appropriate zip header needed for the files.

This would mean we are still recreating the entire zip during each build, but we are only recompressing data that has changed.  The rest would just be written as-is which is very fast since it is a straight write-to-disk.  And if a data file changes, its cache is destroyed, so next build-pass it would be recreated.

However, I'm not sure such a thing is possible.  Is it, and if so, is there any documentation to show how one would go about attempting this?

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't just zip each file individually? Do you see a large file size gain by putting them all in a giant zip file?

Comment: Try looking at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410533/deflate-compression-stream-where-pre-compressed-data-can-be-inserted-does-a-ne/1435813#1435813)

Comment: Zip-files are not "solid archives". It should be possible.

Comment: The only sane approach here I can think of is to just not compress them at all.  Just create a directory structure that resembles the .zip archive organization and just copy files.  Belongs in source control btw.  Compress them when nobody is looking and waiting for it to be done.

Comment: To Ryan, they have to be zipped together as the files are part of a single package and are versioned together.  Plus, a user may download a package from the web which is much easier bringing down a single file rather than thousands. To Hans, I would completely refute your "sane" approach as being the exact opposite. Downloads would be a nightmare uncompressed let alone individually. And what does any of that have to do with source control (which they are already under)? Source is for maintaining version history, etc. We are talking installation and packaging of data to go to the end user.

Comment: @icemanind Wow!! Holding a deflate stream open for a very very long time and just appending as things come along in whatever order is appropriate!  Ingenious!  (I still think there's a format solution as usr suggests)  Note: JAR/Sun/Oracle ought to know something about this I would guess.

Comment: @Icemanind, I don't believe that will work here as again, *any* of the files could be updated during the development stage.  If a file changed that was in the middle of the archive, how would that help?  We're hoping to have each file's 'compressed chunk' of data cached to disk. If the file changes, we nuke the cache, recompress that file and store that as the new cache.  Then when we make the final zip, we simply append all the caches to a master file, then fill in the header information for the zip as needed, thus avoiding the actual re-compression of every file that didn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.  The most straightforward approach would be to zip each file individually into its own associated zip archive with one entry.  When any file is modified, you replace its associated zip file to keep all of those up to date.  Then you can write a simple program to take a set of those single entry zip files and merge them into a single zip file.  You will need to refer to the documentation in the [PKZip appnote](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).  Take a look at that.

Now that you've read the appnote, what you need to do is use the local header, data, and central header from each individual zip file, write the local header and data as is sequentially to the new zip file, and save the central header and the offsets of the local headers in the new file.  Then at the end of the new file save the current offset, write a new central directory using the central headers you saved, updating the offsets appropriately, and ending with a new end of central directory record with the offset of the start of the central directory.

*Update:*

I decided this was a useful enough thing to write.  You can get it [here](http://zlib.net/zipknit16.tar.gz).

Comment: +1. Wikipedia has readable description on the zip format too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)

Comment: Looks very promising!  Gonna see if I can whip up a proof-of-concept here and if this info is correct, you'll get the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mark Adler - This made me so happy, but then I came linked from a PHP SO question, and only realized after downloading this was for C#. No change you want to write a PHP extension? ;)

Comment: Sorry, no.  It shouldn't be too hard to translate.

Comment: The http://zlib.net/zipknit15.tar.gz link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

You could zip each file before hand, and then "zip" them together with no compression at the end to quickly aggregate them into a distributable package. It won't be as efficient as compressing all the data at once, but should be faster to make modifications.

Comment: Yeah, we were thinking about that, but then that requires them to each file to be unzipped individually after the main 'wrapper' zip is unpacked, moving the large build times from our install build to the user's install, which would ruin their experience as unzipping 1000 files individually is substantially slower than unzipping one large zip archive with those same 1000 files inside it.  This is more about speed and keeping files together than it is about size.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot seem to locate an actual exe that implements this type of functionality. It appears that most existing tools I've tried that have the ability to merge/update will reprocess(compress) the data stream as you have already stated you saw.

However it seems what you describe can be done if you or someone wants to write it. If you take a look at this link for the [ZIP file format specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), you can get an overview of the structure you would have to parse out and process. It looks like you can pretty quickly go from file to file gathering up and discarding the files of interest, then merging in your new/updated files. You would still need to rebuild a new central directory (refer to section 4.3.6 of the above linked document) within your new destination archive.

After a little more digging, the [DotNetZip Library forum has a message](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/discussions/59613) asking about the same type of functionality which also gives a description just like I described above. It also links to this [document](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/7896) which seems to indicate that support for that may be added to the DotNetZip library for you to further experiment with.

Comment: but possible?  just perhaps

Comment: I wouldn't be 'chopping/merging' headers.  I wouldn't mind rebuilding the header from scratch each time we make a 'package'.  That's why I specifically mentioned compressing each file down to 'an intermediate 'raw' compressed state' meaning without the header info, which we would build when concatenating the raw data together to make the final file. Make sense?

Comment: @MarqueIV Put that way it sounds like you've got it solved...  Or is the stream nature of the compression you're choosing getting in the way?

Comment: That's what's getting in the way.  We want to stay with zip archives, but I don't know how to build a zip from raw-but-pre-compressed chunks representing the individual files let alone how to make those chunks.  Normally you just throw a bunch of files at a compression library and it spits out a zip. Sure you can add to, or remove from that library, but you're still passing uncompressed files to it.  I'm trying to figure out how to pass pre-compressed portions if you will.  That way the only thing left is writing the file (and adding the appropriate zip header info of course.)  Make sense?