# Big file compression using DeflateStream

Tags: c#, zip

I'm trying to write zipstream compression tool, like getting data from 3rd party service, transform it, compress it and then add those bytes to zip archive byte stream and send to another service.
Crc32 is recalculating after every chunk.

Made 3rd party service emulation - reading file by chunk.
This version works, but after extracting i get empty file. But it is not empty - i see data in hex editor. I think there is something with crc32.
But if i compressing the whole file at once, it works just fine.
Here is my question.
Is it possible to compress big amount of data by chunks with deflatestream?
I need to extract this data later with regular zip tools.

```
public async Task<byte[]> Compress(string fileName, IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]> data)
{
    var crc32Helper = new System.IO.Hashing.Crc32();
    var lfh = ZipTools.GetLocalFileHeaderEntry(fileName);
    testResult.AddRange(lfh);
    var bytearray = new List<byte>();
    await foreach (var chunk in data)
    {
        _originalSize += (ulong) chunk.Length;
        var compressedData = Compress(chunk);
        _compressedSize += (ulong) compressedData.Length;
        crc32Helper.Append(chunk);
        testResult.AddRange(compressedData);
    }
    _originalSize += (ulong) bytearray.Count;

    _crc32 = crc32Helper.GetCurrentHashAsUInt32();
    var cd = ZipTools.GetCentralDirectoryEntry(
        fileName,
        _crc32,
        (ulong) lfh.Length + _compressedSize,
        _compressedSize,
        _originalSize);
    testResult.AddRange(cd);
    return testResult.ToArray();
}

public byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    using var input = new MemoryStream(data);
    using var resultStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (DeflateStream compressionStream = new DeflateStream(resultStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        input.CopyTo(compressionStream);
    }

    return resultStream.ToArray();
  }
```

Comment: You should open the `DeflateStream` only once for the entire set of data, and then repeatedly write the chunks of data to it. If you use a `MemoryStream` for the output then it will all need to fit in memory, but you can make the result stream a `FileStream` so it will write to that without needing all the memory.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I tried this approach. Set `DeflateStream` and result `Stream` as fields and defined them in constructor. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @StanislavMuryndin - can you share a [mcve] for that attempt?  It seems like it should work.  Is there a chance the content simply hadn't been flushed yet?

Comment: @dbc https://dotnetfiddle.net/vDdGLU
I can add some ziptools stuff as well

Comment: What is ZipTools? Is it a library? The current code is very strange, why aren't you just using `ZipArchive` and writing the bytes directly? Why are you taking a CRC check anyway, why is that necessary?

Comment: @StanislavMuryndin - For a [mcve] it would be helpful to see a standalone console app that reproduces the problem.  Is that possible?  I'm pretty sure you can do what you want using persistent streams but to show how we need to see how you are using your `ZipStream` class.  Also, can you share a link to the "ZipTools" library you are using?  I'm familiar with [`System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive) but not that.  Thanks!

Comment: @Charlieface ZipArchive doesn't fit for my goals. I want to create first part zip (like headers), then get some data like 100 lines from pg table, convert it to csv file, add it to bytearray which represent zip archive with all necessary things like headers, bit flags etc. And then send this byte array to grpc channel, then get another 100 lines, convert it again and, let's just say, continue sending this very archive. It's like live zip compressing streaming. And when i got last lines of this table, zip it and send, add to this stream central directory with all necessary fields.

Comment: Sounds like you should use `ZipArchive` over a gRPC stream, it's entirely unnecessary to manage the Zip yourself.

Comment: @Charlieface doesn't it mean in this case i need to store all data in memory?
because of that https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24149

Comment: No just dispose the archive and it will flush.

Comment: But doesn't it mean that i need to store all archive in memory?

Comment: @dbc minimal reproducible example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xOq0kAkEWR6T3-5skNI-c8uYkyoJqSzV/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: in this example zip64_one_file.zip file was created by zip64 util. comressed_test.zip - compression results. Csv is data for comress

Comment: After having looked through your external link I'm still confused about what you want to do.  If you want to create a Zip archive containing some content that is copied in asynchronously, you can easily use the built-in type `ZipArchive` for that, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/UYQtZ6.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @dbc thank you for your example. But if i understand it right, i'm afraid it doesn't answer that i'm looking. In your example all comressed data stores inside zipentry stream. You read it asynchroniously and then add to zipentrystream where it compress. But, again if i understand it right, all data stores in ziparchiveentry. And because of this github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24149 issue it doesn't flush to underlaying stream untill ziparchive disposal.

Comment: @dbc My goal is to construct part of zip archive (like initial part with local file headers signature) -> send it or write it -> flush data which has been sent -> construct second part(like get first chunk of data and compress it on fly) -> send it -> flush again -> next chunk-> etc. And in the end, when we read all data chunks, compress it and send, add central directory with all necessary fields.

Comment: @dbc for example. Code from MRE.
first we add localfileheader
`var lfh = ZipTools.GetLocalFileHeaderEntry("test2.csv");`
and in bytes it's something like `PK-e€}Xÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ 8test2.csv
 e€}Xe€}Xe€}X`
actually we can already send this bytes in grpc channel and after that delete this bytes releasing memory.
get first chunk of uncompressed data and compress it. The result bytes we can send and after that delete releasing memory.
and just like that till the end of compressed file.
and after that we add central directory and other stuff.

Comment: @StanislavMuryndin - I'm sorry I'm still not sure exactly what you are trying to do (I'm not sure what are you doing on the sending side vs the receiving side), so I'm going to have to bow out of this discussion.  Sorry I can't be of help.  But maybe [Can you pre-compress data files to be inserted into a zip file at a later time to improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19454303) is relevant.

Comment: @dbc That's ok. My english is far from perfect, and probably i just can not explain whar i want to achive. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to adapt the C code in [zipflow](https://github.com/madler/zipflow) to use in your C# application. zipflow takes in chunks of data and streams out a zip file, without ever having to keep either the entire input of any entry or the output zip file in memory or the file system.

I don't know what "ZipTools" is, nor can I find it. However writing multiple deflate streams to a single entry will not work. It needs to be a single deflate stream. Also there is no evidence of writing an end-of-central-directory record, which must follow the central directory.

Comment: ZipTools is just a bunch of static methods which produces different zip entries byte after byte. Basically ziptools is for assembling zip archive. CDFH, zip64EOCDR, zip64EOCDL and EOCDR there. Thank you for your tip about zipflow, sir. much appreciate it

Comment: Can you provide a link to this "ZipTools"?

Comment: https://github.com/exelsior/ziptools/blob/master/MRE/ZipTools.cs

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you are messing around with central directories and building the Zip manually. None of this is necessary as you can use `ZipArchive` to do this in one go.

Furthermore, you can't compress chunks of bytes like that and then just concatenate them. The Deflate algorithm doesn't work that way.

Your concern about flushing is misplaced: if the `ZipArchive` is closed then everything is flushed. You just need to make it leave the stream open once you dispose it.

I would advise you to only work with `Stream`, but you could use `byte[]` or `Memory<byte>` if absolutely necessary.

```cs
public async Task<Memory<byte>> Compress(string fileName, IAsyncEnumerable<Memory<byte>> data)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        var entry = zip.CreateEntry(fileName);
        using var zipStream = entry.Open();
        await foreach (var bytes in data)
        {
            zipStream.Write(bytes);
        }
    }
    return new ms.GetBuffer().AsMemory(0, (int)ms.Length);
}
```

If you want to avoid even the `MemoryStream` and upload directly to `HttpClient` then you can use a custom `HttpContent` that "pulls" the data as and when needed.

This example is taken from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=net-8.0#examples).

```cs
public class ZipUploadContent : HttpContent
{
    private readonly string _fileName;
    private readonly IAsyncEnumerable<Stream> _data;

    public MyContent(string fileName, IAsyncEnumerable<Stream> data)
    {
        _fileName = fileName
        _data = data;
    }

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = 0;
        return false;
    }

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext? context)
        => SerializeToStreamAsync(stream, context, CancellationToken.None)

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext? context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true);
        var entry = zip.CreateEntry(_fileName);
        await using var zipStream = entry.Open();
        await foreach (var inputStream in _data.WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
        {
            inputStream.CopyToAsync(zipStream, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    protected override void SerializeToStream(Stream stream, TransportContext? context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => Task.Run(() => SerializeToStreamAsync(stream, context, cancellationToken)).Wait();
}
```

Comment: He wants to stream out the zip file without having to keep the whole thing in memory or in the file system. `ZipArchive` can't do that. It seeks on the zip file, so you need to retain the whole thing somewhere until it's done. Only then can you send it out. It is possible to do what he wants, but not with the usual zip tools.

Comment: Then possibly a custom "pulling" `HttpContent`, which can write to the stream directly. `ZipArchive` does not anymore require a seekable stream nor does it buffer if you are using `ZipArchiveMode.Create` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchivemode?view=net-8.0

Comment: Ok. I would test it on large inputs to verify that the memory usage is constant and independent of the size of the input.

Comment: @MarkAdler You can see exactly what's going on in the source code https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cc7bf831f02cad241547ebea5c56c82f12a50999/src/libraries/System.IO.Compression/src/System/IO/Compression/ZipArchive.cs#L132

Comment: My comment stands. No amount of code inspection, no matter how intensive or thorough, can take the place of a single test.